# Python3: Limit Queue produced by Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm running both I/O Bound and CPU Bound task. Where `multiprocessing` is used for crawling website from `multiprocessing.Queue()`, which parse it's HTML to extract links, and `threading` is used to read a text file that contains list of subdomain from giant marketplace sites (shopee.com and tokopedia.com)

```
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Process, Queue

tasker = Queue(cpu_count()*10)

def consumer():
    while True:
        task = tasker.get()
        if task is None:
            break
        print(task)

def adding_task():
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tasker.put(line.strip())
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        tasker.put(None)

def producer():
    add_task = Thread(target = adding_task)
    add_task.start()
    procs = []
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        p = Process(target = consumer)
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
    
    #Suspected problem.
    add_task.join()

producer()
```

The problems is: `Queue` is growing faster than `multiprocessing` could finish the task. Currently, I'm using this to check if the task is empty:

```
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
from netaddr import IPNetwork
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Process, Queue

tasker = Queue(cpu_count()*10)
ips = '173.245.48.0/20'

def consumer():
    while True:
        task = tasker.get()
        if task is None:
            break
        print(task)

#Check if Queue is empty or full: tasker.full()
def check_tasker():
    while True:
        if tasker.empty():
            break
        pass

def adding_task():
    for ip in IPNetwork(ips):
        check_tasker()
        tasker.put(str(ip))
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        tasker.put(None)

def producer():
    add_task = Thread(target = adding_task)
    add_task.start()
    procs = []
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        p = Process(target = consumer)
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
    
    add_task.join()
    exit()

producer()
```

Is there a better way to temporarily stop `threading` if `multiprocessing.Queue` has reach N amount of task? and continue if it's decreased?

Comment: You're setting the size to 10 x the CPU count.  `tasker.put` should block when you reach that size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue is already bounded:

```
tasker = Queue(cpu_count()*10)
```

That's the only limit you need. The capacity bound *already* stops new tasks from being added if the queue is at max capacity. (OS-level limits on the size of the underlying pipe may prevent adding items even before the queue reaches nominal capacity.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming, At first, I thought I need more checking on the Queue.